# How to pass data to a viewmodel in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro

This is probably a very simple question, but at this time I have myself so confused I can't see the answer. Simply put, I have a window that contains a content control. I'm using Caliburn.Micro's conventions to "locate" the view.

The window looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Views.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MyViewModel" Height="Auto" Background="Blue"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view itself is successfully found, and the screen displays as I expected. However, MyViewModel needs to make a service call to get information based on what is typed into the text box.

So, what I can't seem to figure out is how one would pass that information from the text box to the view model. I've thought of several options, but they all seem to be too much work which makes me think that I'm missing something simple.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When do you want to pass data to MyViewModel?  Does some event take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said there are a number of things you can do:

1. You could expose a property on `MyViewModel` and set it within
   `MainWindowView`.
2. You could use the `EventAgregator`, publish an event from the
       `MainWindowView` and subscribe to that event from `MyViewModel`.
3. Using MEF you could inject a shared resource between the two
   ViewModels, set it in `MainWindowViewModel`, and be able to access it
   from `MyViewModel`.

Comment: thanks for the ideas. Regarding #3, we don't use MEF. Is there another way we could do that? Say with a normal DI toolkit.

Comment: Sure, I sometimes create a SharedData class implementing ISharedData.  It should be no problem to property or constructor inject a shared instance with the other DI tools.